# Is "entailed" the right word here?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I want to use an advanced (not very common word) in this sentence. So I chose to use "entailed". Is it wrong the way I wrote the sentence? If yes, please give a suggestion of another word that would fit in this phrase but it doesn't have to be a mainstream. Like involved, used, etc.

> In this presentation, I will explain the different stages **entailed** in the process of building a new house.

Comment: It would help if you explained in your own words what the term should mean.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to use ***less*** common, ***more*** complex phrasing here. Just *explain the different stages **of** [the process of] building a new house* (where *the process of* doesn't really contribute anything either).

Comment: "Entail" has an aspect of things involved being required or necessary. If that is what you meant then it is good. Otherwise, maybe not.

Comment: @puppetsock yes I mean that all these steps are required and necessary in the process of building a house. You cannot build a house without following them. So I assume i can still use entail right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rather hard to write any more than just "Yes". As you know, 'entailed' is a quite unusual word, so it would not be understood by those with a low reading level, but has been correctly used.